# Standard development platform for the web browsers

Tags: browser

Until recently I hadn't done much work for the web. I found the various inconsistencies about the way different browsers handle CSS and JavaScript quite annoying. I was wondering why hasn't anyone created something like the JVM for the browsers? I mean like a layer that runs on top of the browser which you can write code for and is consistent for all browsers? I know nothing about browsers so this question might be stupid.

Answer (score 0):

[Adobe Flash](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/) or [Microsoft Silverlight](http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/)